# SELECT INTO Statement Failed

Tags: sql-server-2008

Can you guys guide me as to why this does not work?

```
SELECT AN.an_id, AN.an_name, 
    (SELECT TOP(1)ex_date
        FROM upd_exam_headers
        WHERE HS.an_id = AN.an_id
        ORDER BY ex_date desc), 
        sum(ex_fee)
INTO upd_nc_felines AS FS
FROM upd_animals AS AN
LEFT JOIN upd_exam_headers AS HS ON HS.an_id = AN.an_id
LEFT JOIN upd_exam_details AS DS ON DS.ex_id = HS.ex_id
WHERE an_type = 'cat' and an_status = 'NC'
GROUP BY AN.an_id, AN.an_name;
```

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: Try `INTO upd_nc_felines` without the `AS FS`

Comment: An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.
Msg 1038, Level 15, State 5, Line 1

Comment: Your subquery and the sum do not have aliases, so SQL doesn't know which columns of upd_nc_felines to put them in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message says what it means :)

Add an alias to `sum(ex_fee)`

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to this, hope should work,

```
WITH TMP AS (
SELECT 
AN.an_id, AN.an_name, 
(SELECT TOP 1 ex_date         
FROM upd_exam_headers
WHERE HS.an_id = AN.an_id
ORDER BY ex_date desc) AS 'ex_date', 
sum(ex_fee) AS 'ex_fee'

FROM upd_animals AS AN
LEFT JOIN upd_exam_headers AS HS ON HS.an_id = AN.an_id
LEFT JOIN upd_exam_details AS DS ON DS.ex_id = HS.ex_id
WHERE an_type = 'cat' and an_status = 'NC'
GROUP BY AN.an_id, AN.an_name;

)
SELECT * INTO
upd_nc_felines
FROM TMP
```